# Getting all keys from JSON array in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using knockout.js for the first time and have an array as following:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.calls = ko.observableArray([
        { description: 'Create a new project', url: '/feeds/create', method: 'Get', params: [{ success: "true", token: "123adfds1" }] },
        { description: 'Get info', url: '/feeds/info', method: 'Get', params: [{ success: "true", token: "123adfds1" }] },
    ]);
}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

And I can get them using the foreach statement as such:

```
<tbody>
<!-- ko foreach: { data: calls, as: 'call' } -->
    <tr> 
        <td><span data-bind="text: description"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: url"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: method"></span></td>
        <!-- ko foreach: params -->
        <td>
            <span class="params" data-bind="text: $data"></span>                            
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <td class="last"><a href="" class="btn btn-mini">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
<!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

My only problem is that I don't always know the name of all elements in the "params" array and I would therefore like to list all elements.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It confuses the picture a little bit that your "params" is not only an object with an unforeseeable number of properties on it, but is apparently an array of objects with an unforeseeable number of properties on each of them.  However, one solution might be to add a new "computed" property to your view model entries as follows:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.calls = ko.observableArray([
        { description: 'Create a new project', url: '/feeds/create', method: 'Get', params: [{ success: "true", token: "123adfds1" }] },
        { description: 'Get info', url: '/feeds/info', method: 'Get', params: [{ success: "true", token: "123adfds1" }] },
    ]);

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.calls(), function(elem) {
        elem.parameterNames = ko.computed(function () {
            var keys = [];
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(elem.params, function (paramEntry) {
                for (var key in paramEntry)
                    keys.push({ key: key, value: paramEntry[key] });

            });

            return keys;
        });
    });
}
```

This flattens your structure with its unanticipated property names into a collection of standardized "key" / "value" entities.  Then your Knockout binding could look something like this (note that the uppermost binding is against the new computed property "parameterNames" instead of being against "params").

```
    <!-- ko foreach: parameterNames -->
    <td>
        <span class="params" data-bind="text: key"></span> - <span class="params" data-bind="text: value"></span>                       
    </td>
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

I think knockout will only foreach over arrays. You could try this:

```
<td data-bind="foreach: { data: Object.keys(params) }">
    <span data-bind="text: params[$data]"></span>
</td>
```

Do note Object.keys will only work in modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks! Tried it out but it didn't do the job! :)